# Visual Studio 2015 Excel Debugger not working

Tags: excel, debugging, visual-studio-2015

A few weeks ago my Visual Studio 2015 excel debugging just stopped working and it's driving me crazy.

So, this is the problem, I create an empty Excel Ribbon, no logic, just the stubs and I hit the debug button. VS starts excel and whilst loading following Exception pops up:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\Office15\excel.exe'. Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x73921620, on thread 0x1674. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Since I am using my work's laptop, my guess is that an office update has been installed and broke VS, but there is nothing I can do about that.
I already reinstalled VS and updated it to the latest version.
If I start the Ribbon without debug settings, it works just fine.

I am using Office 15.0.4797.1003 and VS 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was caused by EMET.

If you have EMET installed on your machine, open up the GUI, click on Apps, find the row for Excel, and either disable the EAF checkbox or remove the row entirely.

[image]

[image]

Or just uninstall EMET completely if that's an option for you.